# How to change content of Html page automatically When i was editing in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a dynamic html page and I open it in home.html page by clicking on open the content of dynamic html page in text editor. When i edit the content in text editor i want those changes to appear in the dynamic html page automatically

I have created dynamic html page content

```
<h1>This is my first content</h1>
<h2>This is my first content</h2>
<h3>This is my first content</h3>
<h4>This is my first content</h4>
<h5>This is my first content</h5>
```

AND i opened in home.html

```
$(function () {
    load_home();
});
function load_home() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object style="width:100%; height:1000px; overflow-y:hidden;" type="text/html" data="Responce.html" ></object>';
}
```

AND i opened the content in iframe by click on edit button

```
<iframe id="texteditor" src="Responce.html" name="texteditor" style="width: 100%; height: 74%;"></iframe>
```

When i edit the content in text editor i want the changes to show in the dynamic html page automatically.

Comment: are we supposed to code ?

Comment: first of all: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
If you want all code, maybe you want to hire someone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988855/7105338). It might be possible solution for your question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the time to read the [tour] along with [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

you can use the location object to redirect to a page within JS:

```
window.location.href = "/redirect.html";
```

not sure what do you mean in your second sentence though, redirecting to a page means that the page you are redirecting from gets unloaded.

In case you want to just open a window and write some text into it without redirecting anything, you can use window.open instead:

```
var myWindow = window.open();
myWindow.document.write("<your text>");
```